# camera in position specific. three.js

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, position

I want to put the camera in a specific position, then what I do is move the camera and adapt it to the position you want to know the coordinates put this in the "update"

```
console.log (camera.position);
```

then I write these values to position the camera the next time you run my application for example. in the console.log values were

```
x: 2.4457938219139463, y: 0, z: 17.37913738929295
```

then in my code I set the new values.

```
camera.position.set (2.4457938219139463, 0, 17.37913738929295)
camera.lookAt (scene.position);
```

and HOWEVER, the positions are not the same as previously put, the camera appears located in a more or less near point but not the one set above quice

Comment: what is the camera position after you set it?

Comment: @gaitat position to which I want this camera:  http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-1-9431430.html            after: http://subefotos.com/ver/?6b6705201a100bcf6d5d8f492f163d03o.png

Comment: so the difference is at the 14th decimal digit!!! It can easily be a floating error.

Comment: @gaitat but then how he would solve this problem, this error did not think it ever occurring by 14th decimal digit ... Or give me solution or way to place the camera at a certain point I want?

Comment: why do you need 14th decimal digit accuracy?

Comment: @gaitat what happens is not always the difference is 14, and the value is usually several times in x, y and z. I do not understand your question, what method do you recommend to place the camera anywhere and hence the desired position to place the next time my code is executed.

Comment: @gaitat i dont understand about "so the difference is at the 14th decimal digit!!! It can easily be a floating error. " what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a javascript float precision - 7 digits after dot if 32OS and 13 digits after dot if 64OS. So, you dn't need use more then 7 digits accuracy and you need use round. Some like this - `lat.toFixed(7)/1;`

See this output:

**code**

```
var x = 2.44579380000034;
var y = 0.0000000000001;

console.log(x);
console.log(x+y);

var x = 0.1;
console.log(x);
console.log(x*x);
console.log(x*x*x);
console.log(x*x*x*x);
console.log(x*x*x*x*x);
console.log(x*x*x*x*x*x);
```

**output**

```
2.44579380000034
2.4457938000004398

0.1
0.010000000000000002
0.0010000000000000002
0.00010000000000000003
0.000010000000000000004
0.0000010000000000000004
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ssznwn4m/

P.S. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: I do not understand I mean I should do to each coordinate for example:

camera.position.set (x.toFixed (7) /1,y.toFixed (7) / 1 z.toFixed (7) / 1;)

Comment: In principle, this means it is especially floating point numbers. And what if your application is not important accuracy after 7-13 decimal places, it makes no sense to pay attention to it. If it is, for whatever reason, it is important for you, you can use a particular method of rounding. For example, this: `x.toFixed(7)/1`.

Comment: function render() {
         renderer.render( scene, camera );
         ((camera.position.y).toFixed(7)/1),((camera.position.z).toFixed(7)/1));